# Running flask app by executing the subprocess.Popen command

Tags: python, flask

Currently I am starting my flask server by executing the `FLASK_APP=name_of_my_app.py && flask run` (I am on Ubuntu). I need to achieve the outcome of initiating the server as above through different means - namely, by running something of the kind: `python start_same_server.py`. After some refactoring, this does not work for me because it breaks my `socket.io` (flask-socketio). So I had an idea of just creating a supplementary `start_server.py` module that looks like this:

[image]

Please ignore the Windows shell command (it may be wrong, I have not tested it yet). But I am getting an error in my shell when I do `python start_server.py`:

```
/bin/sh: 1: flask: not found
```

It is because of my lack of understanding on how Popen runs shell commands. How do I make Popen see my `flask` command? (I had an idea of adding flask to sys.path? Also can `python -m flask` help here somehow?)

Sorry for the noob question. And thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you run this exact command from the terminal, without Python?

Comment: yeap, I can....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the path to the `flask` command in the virtualenv, like `/home/user/venv/bin/site-packages/flask`. `flask` is not installed to the system, it's just module in the Python virtualenv.

Comment: hmm. let me try that. That would be equivalent of adding that path to the sys.path I think

Comment: there is no flask module there. There is a \__main__.py file which is alias for flask run. But when I do python /../../__main__.py it tells me that: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.cli'; '__main__' is not a package. i.e. it does not see the whole package

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Python -m pip install flask
#or ...-m easy_install flask
```

Why not you try this for the batter result

```
from flask import Flask as f,  Merkup as m
app = f(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def main():
 html = open('index.html').read()
 html = m(html)
 return html
```